# Django url pattern

Tags: django, url

This should be an easy question.  I have two url patterns in Django:

```
url(r'^wiki/page/(?P<page_title>.*)', views.wiki_view, name = 'wiki_view'),
url(r'^wiki/page/$', views.wiki_page_index, name = 'wiki_page_index'),
```

When I visit /wiki/page/test, it takes me to views.wiki_view.  This is correct.  I need the first pattern to capture all characters after the "page/", which is why I used .*

When I visit /wiki/page/, it also takes me to views.wiki_view.  This is incorrect.

I could alter the second url pattern to read:

```
url(r'^wiki/page/$', views.wiki_page_index, name = 'wiki_page_index'),
```

Thus, when I visit /wiki/page, it will take me to views.wiki_page_index.  But I'd rather fix the problem instead of avoiding it.

**How do I format the first url pattern so that it won't pick up the instance of /wiki/page/?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place the second one before the current first one.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/
("Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL.")

Answer (score 7):

Change the first one to:

```
url(r'^wiki/page/(?P<page_title>.+)', views.wiki_view, name = 'wiki_view'),
```