# What is the urls.py regex evaluation order in django?

Tags: python, regex, django-urls

I was having some problems with the regex in urls.py (I am a beginner to django as well as regexes in general)

Here is my original urls.py

```
url(r'^name/(?P<name>\w+)/$', 'course.views.name'),
url(r'^', 'course.views.index'),
```

And I was trying to access it using this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/name/blah/
```

My view looks like:

```
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, sam. You're at the course index.")

def name(request, name):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, %s. You're at the course index." % name)
```

The result I was getting was that for no matter what input I gave, I would regularly get the "index" function, and not the "name" function. I thought the problem was with the first regex.

But then, I changed the the 2nd one to:

```
url(r'^$', 'course.views.index'),
```

And THIS works just the way I figured it to work!

I understand that "$" means end of line, but **shouldnt the 1st regex have been evaluated first? What is the order in which these expressions are matched?**

**Adding a "$" to every url is not that big a deal, but I would like to understand why I am putting it there.**

I am using Django1.4 and Python 2.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the Django [document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/)

> How Django processes a request
>
> When a user requests a page from your
>   Django-powered site, this is the algorithm the system follows to
>   determine which Python code to execute:
>
> 1. Django determines the root URLconf module to use. Ordinarily, this is the value of the ROOT_URLCONF setting, but if the incoming
>      HttpRequest object has an attribute called urlconf (set by middleware
>      request processing), its value will be used in place of the
>      ROOT_URLCONF setting.
> 2. Django loads that Python module and looks for the variable urlpatterns. This should be a Python list, in the format returned by
>      the function django.conf.urls.patterns().
> 3. Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL.
> 4. Once one of the regexes matches, Django imports and calls the given view, which is a simple Python function. The view gets passed an
>      HttpRequest as its first argument and any values captured in the regex
>      as remaining arguments.
> 5. If no regex matches, or if an exception is raised during any point in this process, Django invokes an appropriate error-handling view.
>      See Error handling below.

It said `3. Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL.` So I think this is a bug.

You should add `$` in every url pattern unless [`Including other URLconfs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs)

Comment: Adding a "$" to every url is not that big a deal, but I would like to understand why I am putting it there :)

Answer (score 1):

You're right, the [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/) tells:

> How Django processes a request
>
> When a user requests a page from your Django-powered site, this is the algorithm the system follows to determine which Python code to execute:
>
> 1. Django determines the root URLconf module to use. Ordinarily, this is the value of the ROOT_URLCONF setting, but if the incoming HttpRequest object has an attribute called urlconf (set by middleware request processing), its value will be used in place of the ROOT_URLCONF setting.
> 2. Django loads that Python module and looks for the variable urlpatterns. This should be a Python list, in the format returned by the function django.conf.urls.patterns().
> 3. Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL.
> 4. Once one of the regexes matches, Django imports and calls the given view, which is a simple Python function. The view gets passed an
>      HttpRequest as its first argument and any values captured in the regex
>      as remaining arguments.
> 5. If no regex matches, or if an exception is raised during any point in this process, Django invokes an appropriate error-handling
>      view. See Error handling below.

This is also what [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315048/django-url-pattern) suggests to fix another URL evaluation issue.

Comment: I had gone through this, but this didn't explain why the 2nd regex (url(r'^'...) got matched, and not the 1st (url(r'^P<name>...) in my original urls.py. Does it? 
In fact, as I understand this doc to mean, the 1st one is the one that should have been matched, right? Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: Yes, I'm not clear ^^ After reading the doc once again, it is not mentioned that leaving a URL pattern opened (with no '$') leaves the evaluation opened too ! So for me it's a bug.