# What is in reality the order of evaluation of URL patterns in urls.py in Django?

Tags: django-urls

Although in the documentation it says that "Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL", all the examples are like this:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('articles/2003/', views.special_case_2003),
    path('articles/<int:year>/', views.year_archive),
    path('articles/<int:year>/<int:month>/', views.month_archive),
    path('articles/<int:year>/<int:month>/<slug:slug>/', views.article_detail),
]
```

with more broad URL patterns at the end. And everything seems to work properly.

Moreover, some articles in Stackoverflow suggest that this may be a bug ([What is the urls.py regex evaluation order in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10878103/what-is-the-urls-py-regex-evaluation-order-in-django)).

**What is the real order of evaluation of URL patterns and why?**

Answer (score 0):

The real order of evaluation of URL patterns is different for `path` and `re_path` (`url` intern calls `re_path`, so all statements for `re_path` apply to `url` too).
When we use `path` the order of URLs doesn't matter. However, when using `re_path`, the order of URLs is *specific* URLs to *broad* URLs from top to bottom.